# How can I possibly make a Database Records Navigation Buttons with First, Next, Previous in Asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Can someone show me how to make a database record navigation buttons with First, Next and Previous just like in this link. I need it in Asp.net MVC project

Just like this one but in mvc. please thankyou so much :'(
http://1bestcsharp.blogspot.com/2015/03/How-To-Make-MySQL-Database-Navigation-Buttons-In-C.html

Answer (score 0):

You can bind your data to a jQuery data table. It would take care of the navigations with first, next, previous and last record. You can also set the page size also.

Comment: I need to navigate the database record 1 by 1 , like the one in the link provided.

Comment: in that case, you need to fetch only limited record what you are looking at per page, and need to have mechanism developed which will take the last record ID of the data listed and bring another set of data from DB when click on next/previous button.